The text of a pop-up window is not displayed in the html-markup, how can I check it using python + selenium?
I’m designing an autotest using selenium + python and facing the described problem.
When you click on the "Register" button, a pop-up window with a text appears. I need to check whether the text in this pop-up window is correct.
The problem is this window is not part of the html layout, so I can't access it with selenium. Please, can you suggest how to solve this problem?Pop-up window
The script is below:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from supporting_scripts import generate_random_string
from supporting_scripts import password
from configuration import chrome_options
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=chrome_options)


class Registration:

    driver.execute_script("window.open('https://site.example.com/service/welcome', '_blank');")

    window_handles = driver.window_handles

    driver.switch_to.window(window_handles[-1])

    Button_Registration = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
        ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/p[1]")))
    Button_Registration.click()
    print('Registration click success ✅ ')

    Button_Registration_Check = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
        ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/form/div/button")))
    Button_Registration_Check.click()

    time.sleep(10)


I tried using different libraries and none of them worked for me.
The thing I know for sure is that this pop-up is a browser window, which is shown due to the input rule - type="email"

The URL of the site would be really helpful here. Otherwise you need to trigger the error message and then while it's visible, search the HTML for the text of the message. That should help you find it.

From the pic you shared, it looks like a tooltip. If that is so, then there could be a possibility that the element lies somewhere else in the DOM. As @JeffC said, if you could share the URL, it would be helpful to test and find a solution

Good day.
The link to display this pop-up message is below. You need to click the "Sign up" button and then click the "Sign up" button again.
https://it.videomost.com/service/welcome?lang=en
As the developer said this pop-up error message is not related to the html layout of the page and appears only due to the rule for input - type="email". Using DevTools I can't find this window in "Elements", "Console" and "Sources" tabs. If this pop-up window was just located somewhere in the html markup it would be easy.

@AnandGautam
Please look up to answer your question.

@JeffC
Please look up to answer your question.

That popup you are seeing is default HTML behavior for an INPUT field in a FORM that is marked required. For a simple example,
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form>
    <input required id="username">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>

When you click the Submit button, it shows the same message. So, you don't need to validate it. What you might validate instead is if the required attribute is on the different fields. That way you are confirming that the specific field is required and will display the default message if the field is empty when the form is submitted.

I rewrote your code to simplify it and your locators, added a wait, and added an assert for the required attribute, if you are interested.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


URL = "https://it.videomost.com/service/welcome?lang=en"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(URL)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//p[text()='Sign up']"))).click()
email_id_required = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[name='email']"))).get_attribute("required")

assert email_id_required == "true", "Verify Email ID field is required"

driver.quit()


Thanks. Your solution was the only correct one.
